# Writing to file problems and displaying file contents

Tags: python, dictionary, file-handling

I am currently having problems displaying a file correctly once i have written a dictionary to the file. For this program the input file needs to have the format:
ID: Date: Dayskept: ProductName e.g. 1:12/12/2011:12:A

This is fine the first time I read the example file into a dictionary, but once i save the dictionay into a new file and try to open this file i get the output:
1:"date":12/12/2011, "life":12, "name":A

Is there an easy way to format the data in the dictionary before it is written to file?
Thanks for any advice given

```
    def loadProduct(fileName):
    global cheeseDictionary
    f = open(fileName,"r")
    line = f.readline()         # Reads line from file
    while line:
        line = line[:-1]
        data = split(line,":")  # Splits line when there is a colon
        cheeseDictionary[data[0]] = {"date":data[1], "life":data[2], "name":data[3]} # Stores each split item
        line = f.readline()     # Next line
    f.close()
    print cheeseDictionary

def saveProduct(fileName):
    global cheeseDictionary
    f = open(fileName,"w")
    pickle.dump(cheeseDictionary, f)
    f.close()
```

Comment: Just as a side note the `global cheasteDictionary` lines are totally unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a specific format you want, you're going to need to write code to emit that format.  (I don't know what you're trying to do with `pickle` in there, that produces a binary format that doesn't bear any resemblance to what you say you're getting.)

For instance, you could redefine `saveProduct` like so:

```
def saveProduct(fileName, cheeseDictionary):
    f = open(fileName, "w")
    for i in sorted(cheeseDictionary.keys()):
        v = cheeseDictionary[i]
        f.write("%s:%s:%s:%s\n" % (i, v["date"], v["life"], v["name"]))
```

Comment: Must've forgotten to remove the pickle when I had tried writing to file using that method. Thank you very much for the help code is working fine now :)